# Find files and execute command

Tags: linux, bash

I have a lot of rar archives structured in individual folders and would like to script unpacking them all.

I'm having trouble figuring out how it should be done and need some help.

```
#!/bin/bash
## For all inodes
for i in pwd; do
    ## If it's a directory
    if [ -d "$i" ] then
        cd $i

        ## Find ".rar" file
        for [f in *.rar]; do
            ./bin/unrar x "$f" # Run unrar command on filename
            cd ..
        done
    done
done
```

I am not familiar with bash scripting and I assume the code is wrong more than once. But I guess this should be the basic structure

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use the [`find`](http://content.hccfl.edu/pollock/Unix/FindCmd.htm) command:

```
find -name '*.rar' -exec unrar x {} \;
```

`find` offers the option `exec` which will execute that command on every file that was found.

Comment: `find`, in the way I've posted it, will *prevent* you from too many open file errors. I guess you did something like `find foo* ...`, meaning you've used a glob for the directory name (or something else I'm not aware of). Feel free to ask a question about your particular problem. Drop the link to the question here and I'll have a look there.

Comment: The problem is obviously the `for i in 'ls /var/cpanel/users/';`. It should be `for i in /var/cpanel/users/*`

Comment: @Luka The problem is the `"*.jpg"` - which is unquoted, look at it. It will expand to all jpg files in that folder which triggers that error. The command you are looking for is: `for i in /var/cpanel/users/*; do sudo -H -u "$i" find "/home/$i/public_html" -type f -name '*.jpg' -execdir jpegoptim {} \; ; done`

Comment: PS: If you are happy, please let's delete the comments here, they are misleading.

Comment: Is there some method available which can first print the name of file and then exec?

Comment: @anil yes, `find ... -print -exec unrar x {} \;`

Comment: How would copy files found while also preserving the directory structure? I wish to copy directories but only with the matching files.

Answer (score 10):

You don't need a script.

```
find . -name "*.rar" -exec unrar x {} \;
```

Additionally, you could pass the results of find to `unrar` command.

```
find . -name "*.rar" | xargs unrar x
```